# System.BadImageFormatException in ASP.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, nuget, badimageformatexception, targetinvocationexception

I have a asp.net web application. This is working fine in local PC. But when I try to deploy it on server i got this error msg

> Could not load file or assembly 'NuGet.Server, Version=2.8.50926.602,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.

Here I am publishing the full stack trace error

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Could not load file or assembly 'NuGet.Server, Version=2.8.50926.602, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'NuGet.Server, Version=2.8.50926.602, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'NuGet.Server, Version=2.8.50926.602, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' could not be loaded.


WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].


Stack Trace:


[BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'NuGet.Server, Version=2.8.50926.602, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.]
   Classified.NuGetRoutes.MapRoutes(RouteCollection routes) +0

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +229
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +211
   System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters) +35
   WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager.RunActivationMethods(Boolean designerMode) +445
   WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager.Run() +105

[InvalidOperationException: The pre-application start initialization method Run on type WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager threw an exception with the following error message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation..]
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethodsCore(ICollection`1 methods, Func`1 setHostingEnvironmentCultures) +12619651
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethods(ICollection`1 methods) +12619372
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +280
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +172
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +1151

[HttpException (0x80004005): The pre-application start initialization method Run on type WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager threw an exception with the following error message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation..]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +12618692
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +159
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +12458309


Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34248
```

This worked fine even on server. But don't know what happened. Suddenly I got this error msg. I tried to rebuild and release again. Same thing happened. Every assembly is set to frame work 4. ANY CPU is selected

Comment: Are all the dependencies loaded?
May be check your bin folder if all DLLs are there?

Comment: THis is working fine on local PC

Comment: How are you referring to Nuget.Server? using a nuget package?

Comment: I am just installing nuget packages from them, Like Jquery, Asp.net friendly URLS, facebook SDK like wise.

Comment: enable Fusion, just as the error message says, and analyze the resulting logs for missing assemblies or assembly load errors.